# PHP $_POST variable variables not working

Tags: php, post

I have this problem with variable variables :
even though `$_POST['id']` shows a value when I `print_r($_POST)` , if I try

```
$var = $_POST['id']
```

and then

```
echo $$var // or 
echo ${$var}
```

it doesn't print anything .
Did anyone met this issue and how it can be solved ? 
thanks

Comment: How and where do you define `$$var`?

Comment: Please format your post properly, by checking the SO guidelines, so that people can help you easily.

Comment: You need to show more code/info! What's the content of `$_POST['id']`? And again @NikitaLeshchev 's question.

Comment: $_POST['id']  has  value 1 . $var='$'."_POST['id'] . I am triing to test if isset $$var anthis is not wrking

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php ... `echo $var;`

Comment: `$$` make the variable accessible by it's `$value` ...in this case, depending what `id` had been posted, eg. `$1`.

Comment: This is a dangerously unsafe thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose `$_POST['id']` has value `1` then the following code will echo or print `1`:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

Whereas the following code is trying to echo or print the value of `$(1)` variable as `$id` variable has value of `1`:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $$id;
```

Comment: $var='$'."_POST['id']" and I want to print / test it's content , meaning the value of $_POST['id'] . that's why I need $$var or ${$var}

Comment: You can use `echo '$'.$id;` OR `echo '$'.$_POST['id'];` Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to test if isset  $var and if so , to set another variable to the content of it. I have 7 dropdown lists , each with it's variable name  and 7 checkboxes and I want to write a single function to handle all 7. This is the reason I have to use variable variables . I did it with "clasic" names and it worked but not with _POST

Answer (score -1):

maybe you have a nested structure in $_POST?

```
$good_var_name = $_POST['user_data']['id'];
echo $good_var_name;
```

otherwise

```
$good_var_name = $_POST['id'];
echo $good_var_name;
```

will work

added the code from the comment to the question

Comment: echo "<select name='".$idd1."' ";
    echo "onChange='this.form.submit()'  > ";
    $pid1 = '$_POST['."'".$idd1."']";
    if(isset($$pid1))  $idd1 = $$pid1;
    echo "<option value='0' > ".$textafis." </option>";
    while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_array ($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
           echo "<option value='".$arr[0]."' ";
           echo ($idd1 == $arr[0] )?"selected>":">";
           echo  $arr[1]." [ ".$arr[0]." ] </option>";
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<td align='center' valign='top'>";
if I use $_POST['id1'] , it shows the selected option , but  $$pid1 doesn't

Comment: sorry for the long post but the problem is when using $$

Comment: TIP: dont use $$ within php - rethink your problem and rebuild your code without it  info: dont post unformatted code - no one will actually understand or even read it.

Comment: $$ was the root cause of confusion.